# Why is the Visual Studio 2013 Scaffolding different (Controller vs. WebApi) ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

For the normal read of all entities The Controller version is:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tmembers = db.tMembers.Include(t => t.tEducationType).Include(t => t.tRaceType).Include(t => t.tReligion);
        return View(tmembers.ToList());
    }
```

And the WebAPI is:

```
   public IQueryable<tMember> GettMembers()
    {
        return db.tMembers;
    }
```

Any idea why they are not the same ?

Comment: ...because the Controller returns a View that renders the passed in model (most likely in friendly html), but the webapi simply spits out data (as json/xml) and doesn't do anything more with the model?

Comment: Why does the CONTROLLER use Include? And the WEBAPI seems to enable lazy load by default? (which I needed to turn off in the DBContext constructor to make returning json work)

Comment: `Include` has nothing to do with Web API vs MVC. It'll work either way.

Comment: Does the include someone return in JSON the foreign key entities?  and without it does not ? .. That is weird since with just dn.tMembers I couldn't get the JSON but once I turned off lazy load it worke.d. makes me wonder what is breaking when I leave lazy load on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAPI returns IQueryable to support OData.  If instead you want to just return JSON, set your service to serialize to JSON, and change the signature to public IEnumerable GetMembers()

Comment: So I can append OData commands to the URL and it works ? I never thought of doing that.. right now I just filter in the code.. but maybe theres some advantage to filtering in the url ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the particulars of consuming OData myself, but from what I understand, yes, you just add the selections on the client, and they'll be propogated as selections as long as you're exposing IQueryable.  However this also means remote users can easily cause a giant load on your system.